# Insert to DynamoDB if item doesn't exits

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-rekognition

I'm setting up an attendance check on a streaming video with aws-rekognition, when a person is identified then a lambda should write it to a DynamoDB. the `insertDynamo()`works fine alone(when I'm not calling it as function),but when I put it inside a function, it doesn't write to the DynamoDB table. Any idea on what am doing wrong?

```java
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var today = new Date();
var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
var hour = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    //console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));


    event.Records.forEach((record) => {

            // Kinesis data is base64 encoded so decode here
            const load = new Buffer(record.kinesis.data, 'base64').toString('ascii');
            const payload = JSON.parse(load);
           if(payload.FaceSearchResponse != null)
           {
               payload.FaceSearchResponse.forEach((face) =>  {

                   if(face.MatchedFaces != null && 
                         Object.keys(face.MatchedFaces).length > 0)
                   {
                       var id = JSON.stringify(face.MatchedFaces[0].Face.ExternalImageId, null, 4);
                       //this is hard code it ---needs to split string from kinesis(id)
                       insertDynamo(date,hour,'0001');
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       //do nothing
                   }
               });
           }
        });
    return `Successfully processed ${event.Records.length} records.`;
};

var insertDynamo = function(date,hour,id){
    exports.handler = async (event,context) => {
    const documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
    let responseBody = "";
    let statusCode = 0;

    const params = {
        TableName: "users",
        Item:{
            badgeNumber: id,
            assistance:{
                date:date,
                hour:hour
            }
        },
        ConditionExpression: 'attribute_not_exists(badgenumber)'    
    };

    try {
        const data = await documentClient.put(params).promise();
        responseBody = JSON.stringify(data);
        statusCode = 201;
    } catch (err) {
        responseBody = `Unable to put product: ${err}`;
        statusCode = 403;
    }    

    const response = {
        statusCode: statusCode,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body:responseBody
    }
    return response
}
};
```

Comment: Is an error thrown? Are you getting any response from Dynamo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your lambda function will finish immediate when it has been called, because you use `.forEach` to loop through all the records. This mean all your requests to insert to DynamoDB will be cancel before they finish their yobs.

I have 2 solutions for your case:

1. Wait until lambda callback stack is clear

   Just prepend a "config" line to your lambda function

   ```
      context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = true;
   ```
2. Use old school for loop instead of `forEach` (recommended). `forEach` use callback style to solve each item, then it will not work as our expectly with `async/await` keyword.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var today = new Date();
var date = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate();
var hour = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  //console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));

  for (const record of event.Records) { // for of instead of forEach
    const load = new Buffer(record.kinesis.data, 'base64').toString('ascii');
    const payload = JSON.parse(load);
    if (payload.FaceSearchResponse != null) {
      for (const face of payload.FaceSearchResponse) { // for of instead of forEach
        if (face.MatchedFaces != null &&
          Object.keys(face.MatchedFaces).length > 0) {
          var id = JSON.stringify(face.MatchedFaces[0].Face.ExternalImageId, null, 4);
          //this is hard code it ---needs to split string from kinesis(id)
          await insertDynamo(date, hour, '0001'); // wait until task finish then solve next item
        }
        else {
          //do nothing
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return `Successfully processed ${event.Records.length} records.`;
};

var insertDynamo = function (date, hour, id) {
  // What is this?????????
  // exports.handler = async (event, context) => {

  // }

  const documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

  const params = {
    TableName: "users",
    Item: {
      badgeNumber: id,
      assistance: {
        date: date,
        hour: hour
      }
    },
    ConditionExpression: 'attribute_not_exists(badgenumber)'
  };

  return documentClient.put(params).promise(); // enough for us
};
```